# How do I add testFixures as a dependency of a JvmTestSuite with gradle

Tags: gradle, test-suite, java-test-fixtures

I'm using `java-test-fixtures` in combination with `jvm-test-suite`. I'd like my `testFixtures` to be available to both unit tests and my `integrationTest` suite.

`java-test-fixtures` adds `testFixtures` as a dependency to the default unit test suite, along with compile-time and runtime transitive dependencies. What's the right way to add this to `integrationTest` too?

The following works, but it seems a bit repetitive:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'java-test-fixtures'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}

testing {
    suites {
        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation sourceSets.testFixtures.output
            }
            configurations {
                integrationTestCompileClasspath.extendsFrom testFixturesApi
                integrationTestRuntimeClasspath.extendsFrom testFixturesRuntimeClasspath
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can also use `testFixtures(project)`, but *only* if I declare the dependency in a top-level dependency block, with the top-level dependency block appearing *after* the test suite has been declared:

```
testing {
  suites {
    integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {}
  }
}

dependencies {
  integrationTestImplementation testFixtures(project)
}
```

This works, with all the transitive dependencies set up correctly.
Curiously, I can't use `testFixtures(project)` inside the test suite declaration - the following:

```
testing {
  suites {
    integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
      dependencies {
        implementation testFixtures(project)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...fails to evaluate.

Is there a preferred way to have a test suite depend upon `testFixtures`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question! The cleanest solution right now appears to be to fully-qualify the `testFixtures` function inside the test's `dependencies` block:

```
integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {
  dependencies {
    implementation project.getDependencies().testFixtures(project)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently the most succinct (Kotlin DSL),

```
dependencies {
    implementation(testFixtures(project(":project_name")))
}
```

It's possible [the api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#consuming_test_fixtures_of_another_project) changed since you posted the question since it's still being incubated.